# Selectively registering the backward pass of a set of ops on the GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I have a set of ops that are faster on CPUs than GPUs, both in terms of the forward and backward (gradient) computations. However they're only a small fraction of the whole model, most of which is better run on the GPU. Currently, if I just use `with tf.device(...)` when specifying the forward model, and I let TF decide where to place the optimizer (e.g. `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` op), then it puts all the backward pass computations on the GPU, which is suboptimal. Is there some way of specifying that an op and its gradients should be registered on the GPU?

Comment: There is also a kwarg for minimize function of an optimizer, [`colocate_gradients_with_ops`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train/optimizers#Optimizer)

Comment: Another way is to explicitly specify list of variables to compute gradients via `optimizer.compute_gradients`, then add your cpu-computed gradients to list, and feed computed gradients to `optimizer.apply_gradients`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there's no good way to customize the device assignment for ops in the (automatically generated) gradient computation. However, one thing you can do is to register a "device function" using [`with tf.device():`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#device),  (though the documentation for [this function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.device) applies and is more comprehensive). A "device function" is a function that takes a newly-constructed `tf.Operation` and returns a device name, and TensorFlow assigns the operation to that device. This enables you to do the following:

```py
# These are almost certainly faster on GPU, but are just shown as an example.
OPS_ON_CPU = set(["AvgPool", "AvgPoolGrad"])

def _device_function(op):
  if op.type in OPS_ON_CPU:
    return "/cpu:0"
  else:
    # Other ops will be placed on GPU if available, otherwise CPU.
    return ""

with tf.device(_device_function):
  # Build model in here.
  # ...
  loss = ...
  train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
```

...which will place all ops with type `"AvgPool"` or `"AvgPoolGrad"` on the CPU.

Comment: Thing is my ops are not slow because of their _type_, i.e. they're just made up of fairly vanilla ops like `matmul` and such. But the way they're set up (lots of small / thin calculations) makes them much faster on the CPU (about 3x).

Comment: I almost got this working using `op.name` instead as the criterion, as my ops are wrapped inside functions with their own scope. However through the log I noticed that there were lots of `AddN` ops in the gradient calculations that were still being put on the GPU (they had names like 'gradients/AddN_x'), and this resulted in very poor performance still.

Comment: I finally got this working, but it requires more complex logic that tests whether the inputs of an op are coming from a certain node. I.e. instead of the condition being something like `my_op in op.name`, it is `(my_op in op.name) or any(my_op in node.name for node in op.inputs)`